# how to display selected records in yii gridview

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Good day, great programmers, please I am using yii gridview to display students records but I want to restrict the records displayed to just a particular student. please how do I go about this   ...this is my index

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         // 'id',
        'student.first_name',
        'student.last_name',
        'studentFaculty.faculty_name',
        'studentDept.department_name',
        'level',
        'stateOfOrigin.state_name',
        'image',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

This is my controller below

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new StudentsSearch(); 
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams)->ArrayHelper::map([ Students::find()->where('student_id'=> yii::$app->user->identity->id)->all()]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this without adding any extra params to the search function because your `search()` function could be used for the backend by admin too and if you add extra params here you would need to modify them at all places it is called, so change your `controller/action` to the following and assign the `student_id` to the `queryParams` before calling the `StudentsSearch` model

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new StudentsSearch(); 
    $queryParams=Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    $queryParams['StudentsSearch']['student_id']=Yii::$app->user->id;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Just make sure your `StudentsSearch` model the field `student_id` is searched in the `search()` function before returning `$dataProvider`.

```
$query->andFilterWhere ( ['student_id' => $this->student_id ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code with Controller's Index action

```
public function actionIndex(){

$searchModel = new StudentsSearch(); 
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->andWhere(['student_id'=>yii::$app->user->identity->id]); 


return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for something like this:

StudentsSearch model

```
public function search($params, $filterStudentId)
{
    $query = Students::find();
    $query->andWhere(['student_id' => $filterStudentId]);
    // some code
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new StudentsSearch();
    $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    $filterStudentId = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params, $filterStudentId);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```